# Componente p:fileUpload não esta limitando os arquivos contido no allowTypes

Tags: primefaces

Componente p:fileUpload não esta limitando os arquivos contido no allowTypes.
Alguém já teve este tipo de problema?

```
<p:fileUpload id="certificado" mode="simple" dragDropSupport="false" multiple="false" update="msgValidacao" sizeLimit="10000" fileLimit="1" allowTypes="/(\.|\/)(pfx|p12)$/" skinSimple="true" value="#{companyBean.fileCertificate}" />
```

Comment: Ola Jeremias, in mode simple não funciona, apenas advanced, size limit também não funciona neste modo.

Comment: Excelente. Estava com esta suspeita mas não vi na documentação informando tal. Obrigado.